# What are the elements in set $b: S_b =\{(x,y):(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \text { and } y=x/4 \text{ and } y=4/x \}$

Tags: real-numbers

I am completely confused as to how to answer this. I can answer other questions in this topic but this one is confusing me. Help please?

What are the elements in the set:
$S_b=\{(x,y):(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2  \textrm{ and } y=x/4  \textrm{ and } y=4/x\}$

I have found that $x=4$ and $x=-4$, which means that $y=-1$ or $y=1$
Are these the elements ?

Comment: This implies that $\frac{4}{x} = \frac{x} {4}$ which you can solve.

Comment: Hi, welcome! What have you tried so far? Did you maybe try to combine both restrictions, $y=x/4$ and $y=4/x$?

Comment: To be precise, the two solutions are $(4, 1)$ and $(-4, -1)$.  Your answer is correct.  Do you see why those are the only answers?  (Check out the first comment above.)

Comment: Is it because you can only use real numbers?

Comment: Actually, no.  You'd have the same solutions if you allowed complex numbers.  Do you understand the implication of the first comment above?

Comment: Yeah. As they both equal y they also equal each other so you can then solve for x and ultimately solve for y by placing the value of x back into the original equation.